# How can I add an option to resize a bootbox alert

Tags: javascript, bootbox

How can I add an option to resize a `bootbox.alert();` ?

I'm using Bootbox 4.3.0.

```
bootbox.alert("Success",function(){

});
```

Here is the link for the [bootbox.js](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases) library.

Comment: I tried but it's not working. I don't know where to put option size

Comment: Are you referring to on screen width? At a glance I don't see anything explicitly called out in the documentation at http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html for that.

Does using CSS like `.bootbox .model-dialog { width: 123px; }` help?

Comment: Ok, I probably don't get the question. Can you be more specific? What dii you mean with "add size small option"? Do you need to change the size of the modal window?

Comment: @Mr.Web,yeah I want the alert to be small because,my text is only short the word "Success".

Comment: https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/pull/228. The size option is available for `.dialog` and not for alert i think

Comment: @KarthikChintala,how would you do that i dialog ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should assign a custom class to your bootbox-alert and change its width on the CSS:

jQuery:

```
bootbox.alert({
      "message": "Success",
      "className" : "my-custom-class",
      "callback": function() {
          console.log("Success callback");
      }
  });
```

CSS:

```
.my-custom-class .modal-dialog{
    width:200px;
}
```

This will take your bootbox alert and size it down.

This is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x127bjgt/1) with the fix you needed.

If you want all of the alerts to be smaller, just change the original `modal-dialog` class:

```
.modal-dialog{
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modal-lg, modal-md or modal-sm in bootbox, for example I create a function with some options that looks like this:

```js
$.showModal = function(options){
  if(typeof options==="undefined" || options.length == 0)
    console.log("No se definieron configuraciones, usando opciones por defecto");
  var settings = $.extend({
    title:"Modal sin título",
    size:"modal-lg",
    url:"",
    modalClass:"Modal1",
    data:{},
    classBtnDanger:"btn-default",
    classBtnSuccess:"btn-primary",
    lblSuccess: "Aceptar",
    lblCancel: "Cancelar",
    callbackOk:function(){
      console.log("Sin callback ok");
    },
    callbackCancel:function(){
      console.log("Sin callback cancel");
    }
  },options);
  if(settings.url.length == 0)
    console.log("Se debe indicar una url");
  if(typeof bootbox === "undefined")
    throw("Bootbox debe estar cargado");
  else{
    bootbox.dialog({
      title: settings.title,
      className:settings.modalClass,
      message: "Custom HTML Here",
      buttons: {
        danger: {
          label: settings.lblCancel,
          className: settings.classBtnDanger,
          callback: settings.callbackCancel
        },
        success: {
          label: settings.lblSuccess,
          className: settings.classBtnSuccess,
          callback: settings.callbackOk
        }
      }
    });
    $("."+settings.modalClass).find(".modal-dialog").addClass(settings.size);
  }
};
```

There's an option for modal size, this is the class(modal-lg,modal-md,modal-sm)
With this you don't have to modify the original .modal-dialog class.
This is the line:  $("."+settings.modalClass).find(".modal-dialog").addClass(settings.size);

Hope it helps you.